# How do I match two random numbers, then print match in xcode interface builder, using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying my first iphone app. I am stuck now. I have two label that display seperate random numbers. I used a button and IBAction to generate the numbers then pass them to the label. Now I need to determine when the two numbers match and then print "match" in another label. I am trying all kinds of different things but somehow I am missing something. If anyone can help explain how to do this form a code point of view and hooking it into interface builder that would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: Posting some details about how you're doing this and what you've tried already may help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method where you get and show the random numbers you simply compare them and change the text in the third label accordingly.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    // Generate the 2 random numbers and show them in the labels here.

    // Then compare them and show the result in the third label:
    if (randomNumber1 == randomNumber2) {
        thirdLabel.text = @"Match";
    } else {
        thirdLabel.text = @"No Match";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to rewrite the code I had because it was not efficient, and now I used your suggestion and it works! Thank you for the help!